# Production environment variables in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-18.04

I have a rails app where I am including an api key in my controller. In the controller I have:

```
def email_signup
    email_address = params[:email_address]

    url = URI("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    api_key = ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']
    request["authorization"] = "Bearer #{api_key}"
    request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
    request.body = [{"email": email_address}].to_json

    response = http.request(request)
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    Rails.logger.info "api_key is: #{api_key}"
    Rails.logger.info "Email response is: #{response.read_body}" #uncomment to view response/debug
    # redirect_to jobs_url, notice: result["errors"]

    redirect_to jobs_url, notice: "Thanks for Signing Up"
  end
```

In the logging I am seeing:

```
I, [2018-08-17T19:54:17.439705 #24726]  INFO -- : [f0fce3e4-8574-49d4-84f9-a52c8e7cec24] api_key is:
I, [2018-08-17T19:54:17.439807 #24726]  INFO -- : [f0fce3e4-8574-49d4-84f9-a52c8e7cec24] Email response is: {"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}
```

So looks like the env var `ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']` is not being read. But get this...if I open the rails console and enter `ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']` I see the api key/string.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: How are you adding the values to ENV in server? Do you see it `echo $SENDGRID_API_KEY` from shell?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu 18.x server. I have added the variables in /etc/environment. Yes `echo $SENDGRID_API_KEY` outputs the correct api key.

Comment: What are you using as webserver?

Comment: try dumping the entire ENV var to rails.logger.info. That should give you some hint as to what is going on.

Comment: @ArupRakshit nginx + passender @sakur how do I dump all envs? `#{ENV}` won't do it.

Comment: @Lumbee I would suggest you to use passenger to set the env, it will be far easier. By dumping will not help, as i am sure you app is not able to load that ENV ... So tell me if it is possible for you or it will be large work.. Check [Doc](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var).

Comment: Trying to set passenger_env_var in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` but when I do nginx fails on restart.

Comment: Opps...forgot my ; at the end of the line in the config file. Works now  See full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Arup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) for getting to a solution. I took his suggestion and added the environment variables in passenger by adding the following to my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
passenger_env_var SENDGRID_API_KEY <my_key_here>;
```

...and this works great. So odd because even though I had added the env variables to /etc/environment and I could printenv from the console, for some reason the controller in Rails was still not picking up these variables.